# ClassNotFoundException when client connects to HornetQ

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jms, hornetq

I'm trying to build a simple JAR that publishes a message to a queue in HornetQ, and run the JAR from Eclipse. I'm getting the following error. I'm guessing it's related to assembly versions, but I'm not sure how to track it down.

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to lookup [Root exception is java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.core.client.impl.AfterConnectInternalListener]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:36)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:101)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:76)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:77)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:81)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.me.joel.MessageCreator.createMessage(MessageCreator.java:20)
    at com.me.joel.MessageProducerJar.main(MessageProducerJar.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.core.client.impl.AfterConnectInternalListener
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:156)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.BaseProtocolCommand.readResult(BaseProtocolCommand.java:60)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleClientMessage(Protocol.java:146)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver$1.run(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:184)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.core.client.impl.AfterConnectInternalListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:135)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:116)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:870)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:902)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1204)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1677)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1593)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1557)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1235)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:37)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:153)
    ... 6 more
```

This is my code:

```
public void createMessage() throws Exception{
        String destinationName = "queue/test";

        Context ic = null;
        ConnectionFactory cf = null;
        Connection connection =  null;

        try {         
            ic = getInitialContext();

            cf = (ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
            //Topic topic = (Topic)ic.lookup(destinationName);
            Queue objQueue = (Queue)ic.lookup(destinationName);

            connection = cf.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer publisher = session.createProducer(objQueue);
            //MessageConsumer subscriber = session.createConsumer(topic);

            //subscriber.setMessageListener(this);
            connection.start();

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Hello!");
            publisher.send(message);

            //Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

            //System.out.print("JMS Server listening. Type a Key + CR to exit\n");
            //keyIn.next();

        }
        finally
        {   
            if(ic != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ic.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)  {
                    throw e;
                }
            }

            closeConnection(connection);
        }
    }

    public static Context getInitialContext( ) throws javax.naming.NamingException {

        Properties p = new Properties( );
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        //p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES," org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        return new javax.naming.InitialContext(p);
        //return new javax.naming.InitialContext();
    }
```

And my POM dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <!--  <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>  
       <artifactId>hornetq-core</artifactId>  
       <version>2.2.6.Final</version>  
       <scope>provided</scope>  
    </dependency>   -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-core-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>  
       <artifactId>hornetq-jms</artifactId>  
       <version>2.2.18.Final</version>  
       <scope>provided</scope>  
    </dependency> -->  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.18.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>  
       <artifactId>hornetq-logging</artifactId>  
       <version>2.2.6.Final</version>  
       <scope>provided</scope>  
    </dependency>  --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-rest</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>  
       <artifactId>hornetq-transports</artifactId>  
       <version>2.1.0</version>  
       <scope>compile</scope>  
    </dependency>   -->
<!--    <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>  
       <artifactId>netty</artifactId>  
       <version>3.1.0.GA</version>  
    </dependency>   -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.jboss.javaee</groupId>  
       <artifactId>jboss-jms-api</artifactId>  
       <version>1.1.0.GA</version>  
       <scope>compile</scope>  
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
  <dependency>  
     <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>  
     <artifactId>hornetq-core</artifactId>  
     <version>2.0.0.GA</version>  
     <scope>compile</scope>  
  </dependency> 
    <dependency>  
   <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>  
   <artifactId>hornetq-core-client</artifactId>  
   <version>2.0.0.GA</version>  
   <scope>compile</scope>  
</dependency>  
  <dependency>  
     <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>  
     <artifactId>hornetq-jms</artifactId>  
     <version>2.0.0.GA</version>  
     <scope>compile</scope>  
  </dependency>  
<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>  
   <artifactId>hornetq-jms-client</artifactId>  
   <version>2.0.0.GA</version>  
   <scope>compile</scope>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>  
   <artifactId>hornetq-transports</artifactId>  
   <version>2.0.0.GA</version>  
   <scope>compile</scope>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>  
   <artifactId>netty</artifactId>  
   <version>3.1.0.GA</version>  
</dependency>   -->
<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.jboss.javaee</groupId>  
   <artifactId>jboss-jms-api</artifactId>  
   <version>1.1.0.GA</version>  
   <scope>compile</scope>  
</dependency>  
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just mentioned that the hornetq-core-client lib is provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
    <artifactId>hornetq-core-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Which obviously is not and because of that you get ClassNotFoundException on org.hornetq.core.client.impl.AfterConnectInternalListener.

Comment: The scopes as posted are copied from another app, which is working. FWIW, that app is built as a WAR, but it has a variety of classes with main methods that I can use for testing via Eclipse. I just tried changing hornetq-core-client to "compile", as well as both hornetq-core-client and hornetq-jms-client, and I get the same results each time.

Comment: Please explain how your tests are being run.
I mean how in eclipse you run your test.
Because I think jboss provides hornetq and I assume that the other app was running on jboss but you are not testing your code on jboss.

Comment: In the case of this JAR, it has a class with a Main method. When I'm in the source file of that class, the toolbar has a green "Play" type button with "Run As" > "Java Application" options under it. That results in the exception above. In the case of the WAR file I mentioned, the WAR itself is intended to be deployed to JBOSS, yes. However, there are also a set of classes in src/test/java. Each of those classes has a main method, so if I open the source file, I get the same green "play" button, and I can run the test class as a Java application. More...

Comment: The WAR is a project I'm inheriting, so I'm trying to strip things down and understand various parts.

Comment: There is no way to say how your main methods in inherited project is working unless there is enough info about their running environment. The closest guess is that your running environment doesn't have the lib.
I would remove the scope to see if it will be resolve or not.